# Google Play Game Services can't accept invitations

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

We are trying to implement the Google Play Game Services multiplayer features. It seems that all is working fine, until we send an invitation. When the invitation is received and we show the list of invitations using the Invitation Inbox Intent provided by Google:

```
Intent intent = getGamesClient().getInvitationInboxIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX)
```

The only options that are shown are: "Decline" or "Game Info".

A screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0oPS.png

We are testing the service using two accounts both added as testers in the developer console. One of the devices is using Android 4.1.2 and the other 4.0.3, the first one always get that error, however the second one sometimes shows the play option.

Comment: I have the same issue it is working on Android 4.04, but my smartphone running Android 2.3 always shows that error. I think it is because my game status is "Ready to test". What's the status of your game (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ >> Game Services >> Column 'Status')?

Comment: @marnaish My status is also "ready to test". Do you think that this might be the error? Did you tested it on a published app?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that  to have the same client installed  in both divices. It means the same packet and  same  signature. if  you have diferents  clients  they need  to be registered  in the console.